# I am using one label and checkbox,but label and checkbox should generate dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
private void SetAnswer()
{
    StrQuery = "SELECT AnswerID,Answer FROM TBL_Answer where QuestionID='" + QID + "'";
    oDt = ClsConnection.ExecuteSelectQry(StrQuery);
    for (int i = 0;i< oDt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        //if (oDt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            LblAnswer.Text = oDt.Rows[i]["Answer"].ToString();

            chckbox.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using one label and one checkbox but it showing single label and checkbox ,but label and checkbox should generate dynamically depending upon the question's option.

Comment: You should use `Repeater` [control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8f2zez5.aspx)

Comment: can u elaborate..plz..

Comment: If the problem is you can't see the dynamically generated label it's because you forgot to add it to the form: `Form1.Controls.Add(lbl)`

Comment: am not creating project in windows. Am creating in asp.net using c#.

Comment: @Mederic, tag says `asp.net`, so adding controls to Form is not an option

Comment: @Nino Oh sorry I didn't see the Tag just saw the c# code

Comment: @VanajaDasi, you should read about `Repeater` on [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8f2zez5.aspx), see some examples, try to implement something and then go back to SO and ask specific question.

Comment: @Mederic, which is, in fact, c# code :)

Comment: @Nino yeah sorry haha same thing for me since used to coding in both haa